# Wrong syntax of condition in when in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements

I am making a condition in when element, and I am having errors while validating file. I think the problem is with '<' elements but I do not know how that should looks like. issue/volume and issue/number, these are values from nodes

```
<xsl:when test="issue/volume='3' and issue/number < 4 or issue/volume < 3">...</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Post the full xslt, your input xml and expected output.

Comment: And your error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really have said what error messages you got, but for the particular code sample you have shown you do need to escape the `<` symbols as `&lt;`

```
<xsl:when test="issue/volume='3' and issue/number &lt; 4 or issue/volume &lt; 3">...</xsl:when>
```

Or, if you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use `lt` instead

```
<xsl:when test="issue/volume='3' and issue/number lt 4 or issue/volume lt 3">...</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Another option is to use > (like `4 > issue/number`).

Comment: The error was: "Premature end of data in tag stylesheet", so it was problem with < characters, now with &lt; it works.

Comment: If the data is untyped (not schema-aware) then `issue/number lt 4` is incorrect: with the "lt" operator, untyped data is treated as a string rather than being converted to the type of the other operand.